# Extend Facebook Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am using the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook` NuGet package. I would like to exchange a regular token for the extended access token (the one that replaced the offline_access permission).

From Googling around I found the URL should be in this format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=[APP_ID]&
    client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=[EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

So I use the following code:

```
var longToken = await context.Client.PostTaskAsync("/oauth/access_token",
                    new
                    {
                        client_id = fbApp.AppId,
                        client_secret = fbApp.AppSecret,
                        grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                        fb_exchange_token = context.AccessToken
                    });
```

This returns a null. No error or anything. Just a null value.

**Edit:** Also tried the following, which also did not work. But a `GET` seems more logical than a `POST` anyway.

```
dynamic result = context.Client.Get("oauth/access_token",
                    new
                    {
                        client_id = fbApp.AppId,
                        client_secret = fbApp.AppSecret,
                        grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                        fb_exchange_token = context.AccessToken
                    });

                var longToken = result.access_token as string;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully done this as a GET request, not a POST :) Just put the necessary parameters into the URL and request it as a GET request and the response returns the long term access token.

**EDIT**
When you get the result from this, you should parse the query string first (am not sure in C# but maybe you could use this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

After that try to get the access_token property and I got it right on my end. I was doing it in node.js though, but essentially the same flow.

Comment: I am working with `C# SDK`. That is why I tagged this question with `C#` and `asp.net-mvc`. I am not getting a response. That is the issue.

Comment: Instead of using the SDK why don't you make a regular HTTP GET call and see if you get a response?